# Algebraic Torus: Etymology

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, extension-field

I was wondering if anyone might be able to tell me why algebraic tori are called specifically algebraic *tori*? I find it difficult to see exactly how "an algebraic group that can be described as a direct product of finitely many multiplicative groups" is in any sense similar to the more standard notion of a doughnut.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: The algebraic $n$-torus $(\mathbb{C}^*)^n$ is homotopy-equivalent to the topological $n$-torus $(\mathbb{S}^1)^n$. From here it's easy to generalize to arbitrary rings $R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seeing this question recently received an upvote, I feel that perhaps I should label this as answered. Specifically, back when they made the comment in question, I found **leibnewtz**' statement on the matter to satisfy me entirely. Thus, in bigger letters:

> The algebraic $n$-torus $(\mathbb{C}^{*})^n$ is homotopy-equivalent to the topological $n$-torus $(\mathbb{S}^1)^n$. From here it's easy to generalize to arbitrary rings $R$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $S^1×S^1.$ This is a torus, and the product of two multiplicative groups (the complex numbers of modulus $1.$)

Comment: If I'm reading the Wikipedia article correctly, one requires the group to be a produce of _entire_ multiplicative groups. $S^1$ is not the multiplicative group of any field, just a subgroup of such.

Comment: Actually, I see that the Wikipedia article on "Algebraic torus" says that the name comes from analogy with the theory of tori in Lie group theory.  I don't know anything about that.  I wouldn't be so strict with etymology though.